# Customised template to create a pdf using iText and java

Tags: java, itext

I am new to iText. I want to create several reports in the form of PDF using iText(Java). Each and every report will be in a different design . Is there any way to create a template manually? I am using the database data to create  a pdf. Is there any feature in iText which allows me to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The requirement I have is to use iText.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If as template you intend using another pdf and have it as background you do something like this.

```
//Starting a new pdf document
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//This is your new pdf doc
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);

document.open();
document.newPage();

//Get the file of you template, you should use try catch and then close it
//I simply to just show sistem
FileInputStream template = new FileInputStream("template.pdf");

//Load it into a reader
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(template);

//Get the page of the template you like
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);

//Now you can add it to you report
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

//Here goes code of other stuff that you add..
```

Comment: i have a doubt..template.pdf will have my design am I rite?

Comment: Correct, it will be the background of your create pdf, there is metods aswell extracting a part of another pdf, and using this as template to use as components (for example reapeating parts), in your created pdf

Comment: will the template copy the form fields and allow me to fill out the form fields from the template pdf?